# How to return only 10 rows via SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 1 query that returns over 180k rows. I need to make a slight change, so that it returns only about 10 less.

How do I show only the 10 rows as a result?

I've tried `EXCEPT` but it seems to return a lot more than just the 10.

Comment: *Show difference between two queres* Where are those??

Comment: Can you provide us your query ?

Comment: I want to know the difference between 2 cars. Well, which ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LIMIT. This will show first n rows. Example:

```
SELECT * FROM Orders LIMIT 10
```

If you are trying to make pagination add OFFSET. It will return 10 rows starting from row 20. Example:

```
SELECT * FROM Orders LIMIT 10 OFFSET 20
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't support `EXCEPT` (to my knowledge).

Probably the most *efficient* route would be to incorporate the two `WHERE` clauses into one.  I say *efficient* in the sense of "Do it that way if you're going to run this query in a regular report or production application."

For example:

```
-- Query 1
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `someDate`>'2016-01-01'
-- Query 2
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `someDate`>'2016-01-10'
-- Becomes
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `someDate` BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-01-10'
```

It's possible you're implying that the queries are quite complicated, and you're after a *quick* (read: not necessarily efficient) way of getting the difference for a one-off investigation.

That being the case, you could abuse `UNION` and a sub-query:

(Untested, treat as pseudo-SQL...)

```
SELECT
   *
FROM (
   SELECT * FROM table WHERE `someDate`>'2016-01-01'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT * FROM table WHERE `someDate`>'2016-01-10'
) AS sub
GROUP BY
   `primaryKey`
HAVING
   COUNT(1) = 1;
```

It's ugly though.  And not efficient.

*Assuming* that the *only difference* is only that *one side* (I'll call it the "right hand side") is *missing* records that the left includes, you could `LEFT JOIN` the two queries (as subs) and filter to right-side-is-null.  But that'd be dependent on all those caveats being true.

Temporary tables can be your friend - especially given they're so easily created (and can be indexed):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_xyz AS SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...;
```